# get value of checkbox when checked with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

how to get value of checkbox when checked? My problem is I alrdy had a ng-model for other stuff in my `<input>`

http://plnkr.co/edit/wyTRa8FVkGaEPX6BgYXb?p=preview

I want to collect the data so that when user clicked submit, I can get the value of checked checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ng-model` and `ng-true-value` to track what you have selected.
Declare an array to track values

`$scope.selectedValues=[];`

Then use the following bindings

```
<input ng-show="showC || checked" type="checkbox" id="{{$index}}" ng-model='selectedValues[$index]' ng-true-value='{{item.name}}'>
```

See my updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/KWh5CzZa3OcqKjjhocDz?p=preview

Comment: No multiple ng-model on same model are not allowed.